# Highcharts screen fitting issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am generating high charts in my code. At very first time when it gets called, following is the svg code that gets generated

```
<svg version="1.1" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="690" height="475">
```

So the default width that gets generated in svg is 690 and that value makes the chart go out of my screen. After pressing the button to generate the same chart again, the svg code that gets generated is

```
<svg version="1.1" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="491" height="475">
```

Now this width of 491 perfectly fits onto my screen. What is the way to make sure that the chart fits onto my screen first time also ? How can i fix its width ? If I use

```
chart: {
       width: 400
                        }
```

then it does not work on ipad

[image]
Displayed 2nd time (correct)

[image]
Displayed 1sttime (incorrect, gets cut because of container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will most often let the container decide the width and height, so you should apply the correct width/height restrictions to the style of your container-div. For example:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

You may also want to use `min-width`,  `max-width`, `min-height` and `max-height`, depending on your requirements. You can experiment on [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/20gcz0h9/).

To center the chart horizontally you can add `margin: 0 auto` to your style.

From [the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.width) you can read that:

> By default the width is calculated from the offset width of the containing element.
>
> By default the height is calculated from the offset height of the containing element, or 400 pixels if the containing element's height is 0.

Comment: Thanks, but if I let the container decide width and height of highchart, then the first time chart gets loaded, it goes out of boundaries of div, but next time I click , it loads correclty. What can be the issue at first time?

Comment: What do you mean "out of the boundaries of div"? The size of the chart is inherited from the div size (unless you've also specifically set it in the options, but then just remove those specifications).

Comment: Look at the graphs attached with question, first one is correct graph but the I get second one when I open my page first time. It can be seen that data after Aug 7 getting truncated